# Could Voldemort have killed Harry with Muggle weapons?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

May be Voldemort wouldn't stoop to such a low level as to use tools devised by Muggles to do his bidding, but still, after Voldemort became capable of touching Harry after regenerating in the fourth book, if he had just stabbed him with the knife that Wormtail used to cut off his own arm, would Voldemort have been able to destroy Harry once and for all?

It seems that every time Voldemort directly attacks Harry (in Godric's Hollow, in the graveyard, in Hogwarts), the reason his plan doesn't work is due to some kind of magical rebound. Would he have been able to destroy Harry using conventional means, either before or after his resurrection in the fourth book?

Comment: @user13267 - but the answer will be the same.

Comment: I actually think there's a better dupe out there.

Comment: See also [Why didn't Voldemort just Kill Harry the old Fashioned way? With a knife or something else?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/153440/70236) (cc @Valorum)

Comment: @Gallifreyan - That's the one